# Trojan:Win32/Zpevdo в Sfml Visual C++ 15 (2017) - 32-bit

Tags: sfml, антивирус

У меня проблема состоит в том, что при скачивании sfml для Visual C++ 15 (2017) - 32-bit мой анти вирус не разрешает мне установить sfml. Он выводит мне, что это вирус под названием: Trojan:Win32/Zpevdo

Мой анти-вирус: Безопасность Windows

Comment: вы с официального сайта скачиваете? если да, то возможно имеет место ложное срабатывание - добавьте файл в исключение и отправьте файл производителю антивируса для анализа и внесения корректировок в свою базу (в письме напишите False alarm - на это автоматические средства у них срабатывают и письмо с более высоким приоритетом рассмотрят)

Comment: @Zhihar Спасибо за ваш ответ. Попробую.

Comment: скопируй ссылку на файл который ты пытаешь скачать на какойнить virustotal.com. может там действительно вирь, найди этот инсталлятор на офф сайте. если качаешь со стороннего ресурса.

Comment: @Yakov , я скачивал с официального сайта. Спасибо за ваш ответ!